# How to make python download an image from a URL but if the image is already downloaded it doesnt

Tags: python, api

So say from a random api, lets say api.example.com as an example. It sends a random image once you go on it and sends the json for it. So like {"url": "api.example.com/img1.png"}. After de-jsonifying it how can i download the image and save it in some folder, but if its already downloaded so say the image name is taken it will not download it.

Edit: here is my code i done so far.

`

```
url = f"https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/neko"
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
jsonResponse = response.`json()
urll = (jsonResponse["url"])
urllib.request.urlretrieve(urll, "neko.png")`
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You have used the python tag, but you haven’t added any of your code.

Comment: Here is my code, sorry. i forgot to put it in here

`
    import requests
    import urllib.request

    url = f"https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/neko"
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    urll = (jsonResponse["url"])
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(urll, "neko.png")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in this article, i think [os.path][1] can do the job pretty well.
just try to use

> os.path.exists(phot_path)

that should be it.
[1]: https://linuxize.com/post/python-check-if-file-exists/